# MPI and C: loop through file of commands in file

Tags: c, file, mpi, pbs, torque

Hi I want to parallelize a process on 40 cpus, where each job runs 1 process.

I am using C and MPI with the TORQUE (PBS) scheduler on my cluster.

Here is my script.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char FILE_NAME[] = "/home/foo/c/mpi/cov_test/test_command.txt";
const char WRK_DIR[] = "/home/foo/c/mpi/cov_test";
char comm[39][256];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank;
    int size;
    int count =0;
    FILE *in_file;
    char line[256];
    char *pos;

    in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if (in_file == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
            exit(8);
    }
    if(in_file)
    {
            while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), in_file))
            {       /* Remove newline at end of file     *
                     * Maybe not the best way to do it? *
                     * mpicc compiler throws an error   */
                    if((pos=strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL)
                            *pos = '\0';
                    strcpy(comm[count], line);

                    count++;
            }
    }

    chdir(WRK_DIR); 

    chdir(WRK_DIR);

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    /* Saw this on another SO posting */
    int start = (rank*count)/size;
    int end = ((rank+1)*count)/size;

    for(int i= start; i < end; i++) {

            printf("%s\n", comm[rank]);
            /*system(comm[rank]);*/
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The output i only the first command of the file "test_command.txt"

Here is my Torque submission file

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -q condo
#PBS -l walltime=01:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=5:ppn=8
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -o /home/foo/c/mpi/cov_test/pilot_mpi_out

#had to export my perl libraries
export PERL5LIB=/home/foo/myperl/lib/perl5:/home/foo/myperl/share/perl5:$PERL5LIB
cd $HOME/c/mpi/cov_test
/opt/openmpi/bin/mpirun -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE -np 40 ./pilot_mpi_test-2
```

I'm new to C so I might be (probably) doing something ghastly. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 4):

It should be `printf("%s\n", comm[i]);` instead of `printf("%s\n", comm[rank]);`.

Comment: That awkward moment when you think you've gone through everything, and you are sure that the only thing that could possibly be wrong is your understanding of the language... only to find a simple typo like this. Kills me every time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are getting a single line of output when you expect 40. You may want to verify that you are getting output from processes other than process 0. I would add a

```
printf("Processes %d\n", rank);
```

just after the MPI_Comm_size line. If you don't see a line from each process something will need changed in your environment. I did a little looking but my GoogleFu has been failing me this morning. The other option is to pass the strings back to process 0 with MPI.

Comment: you are missing a closing double quote `"` in your answer. SO won't let me edit it, since edits apparently have to be at least 6 characters change :-/